# Function Unique in Excel

Tags: excel, unique

When using the Unique function, an employee with a dm.li account is included in the selection twice (as text and as a link)

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER('монтажники все заявки'!E3:E;'монтажники все 
заявки'!E3:E<>""))
```

[image: Excel Screenshot]

How to get rid of duplicates

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use?

Comment: Excel 2021. Also works when uploading to Google Sheets